# Draggable table: drupal_render, render, both yield an empty string for "#weight" types?

Tags: theming, hooks

I am attempting to implement a draggable table in a Drupal 7 module. Whenever I invoke either `render()` or `drupal_render` on my element of type `#weight`, an empty string is returned. The table does render and I am able to drag the rows, but cannot see the weights. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong: I've explored some core Drupal components that follow the same pattern (of invoking `drupal_render` on a `#weight` type element) and nothing is jumping out at me.

My form begins here:

```
$table_header = array_map(t, array('Order', 'Item', 'Manage'));
$form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'mymodule_kw_table',
    '#header' => $table_header,
    '#rows' => $my_rows // array(string)
);
```

`hook_theme()` is implemented as such:

```
function mymodule_theme()
{
    return array(
        'mymodule_kw_table' => array(
            'render element' => 'form',
            'function' => 'mymodule_table'
        )
    );
}
```

Finally, `mymodule_table()` looks like this:

```
function mymodule_table($variables)
{
    $table_data = $variables['form'];
    $table_id = uniqid('tb');

    $rows = $table_data['#rows'];

    for ($i=0; $i < count($rows); ++$i) {
        $weight = array(
            '#type' => 'weight',
            '#title' => t('Order'),
            '#default_value' => $i,
            '#delta' => 1,
            '#attributes' => array('class' => array($table_id . '-weight'))
        );

        $rows[$i] = array(
            'data' => array_map(render, array($weight, $rows[$i], 'abcd placeholder')),
            'class' => array('draggable')
        );
    }

    $table = theme('table', array(
        'header' => array_map(t, array('Order', 'Item', 'Manage')),
        'rows' => $rows,
        'attributes' => array('id' => $table_id)
    ));

    $table .= drupal_render_children($table_data);

    drupal_add_tabledrag($table_id, 'order', 'sibling', $table_id . '-weight');

    return $table;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weight objects can be rendered with [`form_process_weight()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_weight/7.x)

```
    $weight = array(
        '#type' => 'weight',
        '#title' => t('Order'),
        '#default_value' => $i,
        '#delta' => 1,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array($table_id . '-weight'))
    );

    $weight = form_process_weight($weight);
```